# What are the differences between Business Rules service on Bluemix and Operational Decision Manager?

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I heard that ODM is providing support for "Business Rules" on Bluemix as one of its runtime environments. Could you please tell me the differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

The Business Rules service is built on top of technologies found in IBM ODM on premises, mainly the business rules authoring tooling and the business rule engine execution components. 
A developer using the Business Rules service can develop a rule application using the Rule Designer IDE (available for download from the service), deploy the rule application to the Business Rules service, and call the service from any application running inside or outside Bluemix.

If you are familiar with the on-premises version of the IBM ODM product, note that the following features are NOT supported by the Business Rules service on Bluemix:

- Decision Center
- Decision Validation Services (DVS)
- Local business rules execution
- Customization of the Decision Server
- Interceptors
- Rule tracing using the `ruleset.trace.enabled`, `ruleset.sequential.trace.enabled` properties
- Filters